# Extract gtk/native icon from application under Linux with node.js?

Tags: linux, node.js, gtk, gnome

I need write nodejs function to detect Linux application icons by their names.
I have parsed INI file with application launchers and i need to know where is real locations specified in laucher as icon alias.

Use current paths for looking up icons with `lstatSync`:

```
var USR_PIXMAPS_PATH = '/usr/share/pixmaps',
USR_APPS_PATH = '/usr/share/applications',
USR_DOCKAPPS_PATH = '/usr/share/dock/applications',
USR_64x64ICON_PATH = '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps',
USR_OTHERICON_PATH = '/usr/share/icons/hicolor';

try { (fs.lstatSync(USR_PIXMAPS_PATH+'/'+data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"]+'.png')) && (icon=USR_PIXMAPS_PATH+'/'+data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"]+'.png');    } catch(e) {}
try { (fs.lstatSync(USR_OTHERICON_PATH+'/'+data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"]+'.svg')) && (icon=USR_OTHERICON_PATH+'/'+data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"]+'.svg');    } catch(e) {}
try { (fs.lstatSync(USR_64x64ICON_PATH+'/'+data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"]+'.png')) && (icon=USR_64x64ICON_PATH+'/'+data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"]+'.png');    } catch(e) {}
try { (fs.lstatSync(data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"])) && (icon=data["Desktop Entry"]["Icon"]); } catch(e) {  }
```

This my way to detect gtk icons.

Is there anyway (maybe simple way to extract from binary file) to get application icons path with node-js under Linux or gtklib for node.js (aka pygtk) to get shell icons or any **documentation url**?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: That isn't the proper theme aware way to look up the application's icon given its name. You should call the equivalent of pygtk's `gtk.IconTheme.lookup_icon` in gtklib. (I'd even look it up for you but I can't locate gtklib). (Or you could implement the proper look up from [Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).)

Comment: So i need the same solution for node.js. I'm looking correct folders by Icon Theme Specification (theme is hardcoded) but not all icons are found. For example, "system testing" app